# Persisting Google Map InfoWindow Content across multiple click events

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-api, infowindow

In my Google Map, there are multiple markers with relevant infowindow content. User can click on the marker, view the InfoWindow, interact with infowindow to do some processing in the backend. According to backend(server) response I update the form data in the infowindow. This form data is unique to the selected infowindow and the marker. So far so good.

The problem comes when I click another marker and interact with that infowindow. When I select previous infowindow, it does not maintain the latest state which means the form hidden fields changes and ui button state changes are not visible. The infowindow appears with default content. So, it's clear that each time infowindow regenerated.

What I need is to preserve changes in each infowindow while interacting with other markers in the map. Can someone please give a solution? Thanks in advance.

```
function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $user_lat; ?>, <?php echo $user_lng; ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            center: defaultCenter,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        var markers = [];
        var infoWindowContent = [];
        // Multiple Markers
<?php if (!empty($plumbers)): ?>
            markers = [
    <?php foreach ($plumbers as $result): ?>
                    ['<?php echo $result['first_name']; ?>', <?php echo $result['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $result['lng']; ?>],
    <?php endforeach; ?>
            ];
<?php endif; ?>

        // Info Window Content
<?php if (!empty($plumbers)): ?>
            infoWindowContent = [
    <?php foreach ($plumbers as $result): ?>
                    ['<div class="info_content">' +
                            '<h3><?php echo $result['first_name'] . ' - ' . $result['location']; ?></h3>' +
                            '<?php echo number_format($result['distance'], 2); ?> miles away' +
                            //'<p><?php //echo anchor('plumbers/assign/' . $result['location'] . '/' . $service_id . '/' . $service_type_id . '/' . $customer_id . '/' . $result['id'], 'Assign');  ?></p>' +
                            "<form method='post'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'  value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='plumber_id' id='plumber_id' value='<?php echo $result['id']; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='location' id='location' value='<?php echo $result['location']; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat' value='<?php echo $result['lat']; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng' value='<?php echo $result['lng']; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='service_id' id='service_id' value='<?php echo $service_id; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='service_type_id' id='service_type_id' value='<?php echo $service_type_id; ?>'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='customer_id' id='customer_id' value='<?php echo $customer_id; ?>'>" +
                            "<button type='button' class='btn-assign btn btn-success btn-sm' data-status='unassigned' data-cs-id=''><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Assign</button>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='cs_id' id='cs_id' value=''>" +
                            "<img src='<?php echo base_url('assets/img/loader.GIF'); ?>' class='assign-loader'>" +
                            "</form>" +
                            '</div>'],
    <?php endforeach; ?>
            ];
<?php endif; ?>

        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            //Handle click assign button
//            google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
//                $("body").on('click', '.btn-assign', function(e) {
//                    alert('');
//                });
//            });

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(12);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });


    }
```

Comment: What does the HTML/Javascript look like that the client gets?  What have you tried to persist the content? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your raw infoWindowContent array is re-rendered by the marker click listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a DOMNode as content instead of a string.

A simple example that creates a DOMNode based on the content-string:

```
  //a simple array with latitude, longitude and content-string
  var markers=[
          [0,0,'<div>Marker#1<br/><select><option>a<option>b<option>c</select>'],
          [0,1,'<div>Marker#2<br/><select><option>a<option>b<option>c</select>'],
          [0,2,'<div>Marker#3<br/><select><option>a<option>b<option>c</select>']
              ];
  var InfoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  $.each(markers,function(i,item){
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,
                                       position:{lat:item[0],lng:item[1]},
                                       //create a DOMNode based on the content
                                       //and store it as property of the marker
                                       content:$(item[2])[0]
                                      });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
      //use the content-property of the marker(the DOMNode) as content
      InfoWindow.setContent(this.get('content'));
      InfoWindow.open(this.getMap(),this);
    });
  });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/bojqeres/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/bojqeres/)
(choose different options from the select's and you'll see that the lists will keep their state)